# Unordered list margin doesn't work inside my footer

Tags: html, css

I want the unordered list to be centered in relation to the footer div, but I can't get this to work for some reason. My concern is that my stickyfooter might have anything to do with it, but I really don't know. Help appreciated.

**EDIT:** It would also appear that I cannot `margin-top` any element inside `#footer`.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="footer">
<ul>
    <li>Item1</li>
    <li>Item2</li>
    <li>Item3</li>
    <li>Item4</li>
        <li>Item5</li>
        <li>Item6</li>
        <li>Item7</li>
        <li>Item8</li>
            <li>Item9</li>
            <li>Item10</li>
            <li>Item11</li>
            <li>Item12</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#footer {
    height: 200px;
    background: linear-gradient(#545454, #3B3B3B); /* IE9- needs fix */ 
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -200px;
    clear: both;
    bottom: 0;
}

    #footer ul {
        width: 450px;
        margin: 50px auto; /* This is the part that doesn't work.. */
        font-size: 13px;
        color: white;
        -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
        column-count: 3; /* Standard */
        -webkit-column-gap: 0; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        -moz-column-gap: 0; /* Firefox */
        column-gap: 0; /* Standard */
    }

        #footer li {
            width: 150px;
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 5px;
        }
```

Comment: can't see any problem with that. what is `margin-top: -200px;` for? this might be the problem area.

Comment: that's for my stickyfooter

Comment: the question title mentions about `margin` which does not work while the question itself mentions about centering the list, it's confusing.

Comment: no.. cuz you center the list using margin.

Comment: @abhitalks I also tried removing the margin-top: -200px; but it did nothing to solve my problem.

Comment: @KingKing: perhaps op is talking about the `margin: 50px auto;`?

Comment: @KingKing It's the margin-top part of `margin: 50px auto` that doesn't work. The list itself is already centered horizontally.

Comment: @DuploW: adding an `overflow: auto;` on `#footer` might help. As I see you have applied a `clear:both`, which means you have a float problem somewhere.

Comment: overflow: hidden; worked. Else I get a scrollbar for nothing. Thanks :)

Comment: @abhitalks you should add your solution as an answer and not in a comment btw.

Comment: @DuploW in fact your list is not centered correctly unless you meant the `ul` itself (not the text composed by all the `li` items). If you mean the margin top `50px` is not affected, that's because of the so-called ***margin-collapsing***.

Comment: @KingKing I meant the ul yes.

Comment: The problem is what @KingKing explained to you. Glad you got it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a margin collapse problem.

Look at this demo http://jsfiddle.net/WfGej/
and fix your #footer with

```
   border-top:1px solid transparent;
```

like this : http://jsfiddle.net/WfGej/1/

Comment: Not sure I understand this solution, care to explain it?